# How to add sort functionality with a Button to a Matplotlib bar plot and line plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am just starting out to experiment with visualization in Python. With the following code, I am trying to add sort functionality to a Matplotlib bar plot which is drawn from a data frame. I would like to add a `button` on the graph like `sort`, so that when it's click it would display a new plot in the order from the highest sales figure to lowest sales figure, currently the button can be display yet the sort function cannot be triggered. Any idea or pointer would be appreciated.

[Updated attempt]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def sort(data_frame):
    sorted = data_frame.sort_values('Sales')
    return data_frame2

def original():
   
    return data_frame

data_frame.plot.bar(x="Product", y="Sales", rot=70, title="Sales Report");
plot.xlabel('Product')
plot.ylabel('Sales')

axcut = plt.axes([0.9, 0.0, 0.1, 0.075])
bsort = Button(axcut,'Sort')
bsort.on_clicked(sort)
axcut2 = plt.axes([1.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.075])
binit = Button(axcut2,'Original')
binit.on_clicked(original)
plt.show()
```

Expected graph output

[image]

Integration

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib notebook

class Index(object):
        ind = 0
        global funcs
    
        def next(self, event):
            self.ind += 1
            i = self.ind %(len(funcs))
            x,y,name = funcs[i]() # unpack tuple data
            for r1, r2 in zip(l,y):
                r1.set_height(r2)
            ax.set_xticklabels(x)
            ax.title.set_text(name) # set title of graph
            plt.draw()        

class Show():
        
        def trigger(self):
            number_button = tk.Button(button_frame2, text='Trigger', command= self.sort)
        
    
        def sort(self,df_frame):
    
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
            
            ######intial dataframe
            df_frame
            ######sorted dataframe
            dfsorted = df_frame.sort_values('Sales')
           
    
            x, y = df_frame['Product'], df_frame['Sales']
            x1, y1 = df_frame['Product'], df_frame['Sales']
            x2, y2 = dfsorted['Product'], dfsorted['Sales']
    
            l = plt.bar(x,y)
            plt.title('Sorted - Class')
            l2 = plt.bar(x2,y1)
            l2.remove()
            
            def plot1():
                x = x1
                y = y1
                name = 'ORginal'
                return (x,y,name)
    
            def plot2():
                x = x2
                y = y2
                name = 'Sorteds'
                return (x,y,name)
            
            funcs = [plot1, plot2]        
            callback = Index()
            button = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
            bnext = Button(button, 'Sort', color='green')
            bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)
    
            plt.show()
```

Comment: `plotly` / `dash` are better for this. This question is a little bit too broad in my opinion as there could be a lot of different approaches.

Comment: Okay, edited the question to narrow down the focus. may i know i want to use Matplotlib/Seaborn, which one would be better to add the sort button functionality

Comment: I would create buttons with one button representing the default graph and one button  represnting the sorted graph. To import use `from matplotlib.widgets import Button` and check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47384928/6366770

Comment: You can make your question reproducible by including a `seaborn` dataset as an example. `flights` is a sample dataset, but you can use `sns.get_dataset_names()` to explore other dataset names and pass one of them to `sns.load_dataset()`, e.g. `df = sns.load_dataset('flights')`

Comment: also. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plot` is usually used as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I would be change your syntax on that as it can get confused with `pandas` method `plot`

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. i found it some people tend to use data_frame.plot(..), afterwards plt.show() is used, may i ask are they using matplotlib or just using pandas plot to draw the graph?

Comment: pandas plot. That was especially my point. pandas plot uses malpoltlib  as default though, so really it is using matplotlib but you are calling it from a pandas dataframe

Comment: Hi David, with your suggested example, i've tried to add the sort button on matplotlib graph, the button is shown, but there's no response when clicked, any pointer would be appreciated

Comment: see my answer. This should get you wat you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have included two reproducible examples using the famous `titanic` dataset to a basic comparison of `class` vs. `# of survivors` for interactive sorting for both `matplotlib` `bar` and `plot` (i.e. line) sorting on the x-axis below:

With `bar` plots you have to loop through the rectangles using `set_height`, e.g. `for r1, r2 in zip(l,y): r1.set_height(r2)` and for `line` plots, you use `set_ydata`, e.g. `l.set_ydata(y)`.

Make sure to use `%matplotlib notebook` if using a jupyter notebook.

**BAR**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib notebook

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df1 = df.groupby('class', as_index=False)['survived'].sum().sort_values('class')
df2 = df1.sort_values('survived', ascending=False)
x, y = df1['class'], df1['survived']
x1, y1 = df1['class'], df1['survived']
x2, y2 = df2['class'], df2['survived']

l = plt.bar(x,y)
plt.title('Sorted - Class')
l2 = plt.bar(x2,y1)
l2.remove()

class Index(object):
    ind = 0
    global funcs

    def next(self, event):
        self.ind += 1
        i = self.ind %(len(funcs))
        x,y,name = funcs[i]() # unpack tuple data
        for r1, r2 in zip(l,y):
            r1.set_height(r2)
        ax.set_xticklabels(x)
        ax.title.set_text(name) # set title of graph
        plt.draw()


def plot1():
    x = x1
    y = y1
    name = 'Sorted - Class'
    return (x,y,name)


def plot2():
    x = x2
    y = y2
    name = 'Sorted - Highest # Survivors'
    return (x,y,name)


funcs = [plot1, plot2]        
callback = Index()
button = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(button, 'Sort', color='green')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)

plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

**LINE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib notebook

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df1 = df.groupby('class', as_index=False)['survived'].sum().sort_values('class')
df2 = df1.sort_values('survived', ascending=False)
x, y = df1['class'].to_numpy(), df1['survived'].to_numpy()
x1, y1 = df1['class'].to_numpy(), df1['survived'].to_numpy()
x2, y2 = df2['class'].to_numpy(), df2['survived'].to_numpy()
l, = plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title('Sorted - Class')

class Index(object):
    ind = 0
    global funcs

    def next(self, event):
        self.ind += 1
        i = self.ind %(len(funcs))
        x,y,name = funcs[i]() # unpack tuple data
        l.set_ydata(y) #set y value data
        ax.set_xticklabels(x)
        ax.title.set_text(name) # set title of graph
        plt.draw()


def plot1():
    x = x1
    y = y1
    name = 'Sorted - Class'
    return (x,y,name)


def plot2():
    x = x2
    y = y2
    name = 'Sorted - Highest # Survivors'
    return (x,y,name)


funcs = [plot1, plot2]        
callback = Index()
button = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(button, 'Sort', color='green')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)

plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: May i know instead of a OOP implementation, can i implement it in procedural style, thank you

Comment: @epiphany I adapted it from the documentation and am not sure how to easily implement it without OOP.

Comment: understood, i've tried to implement it in OOP style **[updated in Integration part]** , the Show() class is the main class, currently i would get the bar chart and button to be displayed, yet the click function isnt triggered, seems like it cannot call the next function in the Index Class, any idea in this? thank you